# Creating a frequency table of dice occurrences in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am fairly new at programming and am currently picking up C#.

What I have is two dice rolled at random for 50 rolls
Both dice totals added together to give a sum for each roll.

My question is, how can I create a frequency table that will count the amount of times a certain number is rolled at the end of 50 dice rolls.

Below is what I am trying to achieve. Tally chart of each number rolled (from both dice)

```
1: |||
2: ||||
3: ||||||
4: |||||
5: ||||||||
6: ||
```

Here is my code so far,

```
class Program
{
    const int DICE_ROLLS = 51;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] firstDice = new int[DICE_ROLLS];
        int[] secondDice = new int[DICE_ROLLS];
        int diceSum = 0;

            for (int roll = 1; roll <= 50; roll++)
            {
                firstDice[roll] = GenerateNumber(random);
                secondDice[roll] = GenerateNumber(random);
                diceSum = firstDice[roll] + secondDice[roll];
                Console.WriteLine("ROLL {0}:  {1} + {2} = {3}", roll, firstDice[roll], secondDice[roll], diceSum);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
            Console.WriteLine("Number Frequency");
    }

    static int GenerateNumber (Random random)
    {
        return random.Next(1, 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const int DICE_ROLLS = 51;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] firstDice = new int[DICE_ROLLS];
    int[] secondDice = new int[DICE_ROLLS];
    int[] count = new int[6];
    int diceSum = 0;

    for (int roll = 0; roll <= DICE_ROLLS - 1; roll++)
    {
        firstDice[roll] = GenerateNumber(random);
        secondDice[roll] = GenerateNumber(random);
        diceSum = firstDice[roll] + secondDice[roll];
        Console.WriteLine("ROLL {0}:  {1} + {2} = {3}", roll + 1, firstDice[roll], secondDice[roll], diceSum);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    Console.WriteLine("Number Frequency");

    var allRolls = firstDice.Concat(secondDice).ToList();   
    for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(i + ": ");
        for(var j = 0; j < allRolls.Count(c => c == i); j++)
            Console.Write("|");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}


static int GenerateNumber (Random random)
{
   return random.Next(1, 7);
}
```

Gives:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Number Frequency
1: ||||||||||||||||||||
2: |||||||||||
3: ||||||||||||||||||
4: ||||||||||||||||
5: |||||||||||||||||||||
6: ||||||||||||||||
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is it possible to order it from `1` to `6` instead of how it prints currently. Also, is there something wrong in my code that makes it count `0`? (Something I don't want to show up)

Comment: @InnavoigOki See my edit, it solves both those problems and explains why it was printing the 0s :)

Comment: I have changed the loop and this is what I am getting now:

`ROLL 0:  6 + 3 = 9
ROLL 1:  4 + 2 = 6
...
ROLL 49: 1 + 4 = 5
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Number Frequency
0: |||||
1: ||||||
2: ||||||||||
3: ||||||
4: ||||||||||||
5: ||||||||||||||
6: ||||||

Comment: apologies, I do not know how to write out in the format that you have given Rob. I am very new

Comment: @InnavoigOki I've included the full code, you must have missed one of the lines. Check it against what you've got and the moment. The code should will roll 51 times (giving 102 results for two dice), and the frequency graph only shows 1-6

Comment: Thank you Rob. Can this also be written out without using LINQ? I am fairly new with programming and I feel I will benefit more with the basics

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 6 sided dice, a `Dictionary` might be a good option.

```
var rolls = new SortedDictionary<int, int> { {1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0}, {4,0}, {5,0}, {6,0} };

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
   var first = Random.Next(1, 7);
   var second = Random.Next(1, 7);
   rolls[first]++;
   rolls[second]++;

   // Rest of rolling display code
}

// Header display code
foreach(var roll in rolls)
{
     Console.Write("{0}: ", roll.Key);
     for(int i = 0; i < rolls.Value; i++)
     {
         Console.Write("|");
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You could even easily customize it based on different sided dice by generating the initial dictionary values based on a variable like

```
int sides = 12;
var rolls = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();

foreach(var value in Enumerable.Range(1, sides))
{
    rolls.Add(value, 0);
}
```

The you could replace the `Random.Next(1, 7)` with `Random.Next(1, sides)` and have a pretty generic program for rolling dice and counting their frequency.

Comment: This is awesome. However, I have not come across Linq yet and was wondering if there is a way to write it for a newbie like myself.

Comment: Linq is amazingly useful, but not always necessary. I would learn it sooner than later though as it solves a lot of problems in very succinct ways. This solution does not use it if you are looking for one without it.

Comment: @BradfordDilon I cannot disagree with you here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var rnd = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
            Enumerable
                .Range(0, 50)
                .Select(n => rnd.Next(1, 7))
                .ToLookup(x => x)
                .Select((xs, n) =>
                    String.Format("{0}: {1}", n + 1, new String('|', xs.Count())))));
```

I get this (for example):

```
1: |||||||
2: |||||||
3: |||||||||||
4: |||||||||
5: ||||||||
6: ||||||||
```